# What is being said in this short audio clip? (4 seconds)

Tags: translation

[Here](https://instaud.io/3ghw) is the audio source. My current translation is "You almost got kicked
out of the union. You're so resilient". I got some doubt about the "You're so resilient" part. Is it correct?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: “정신 좀 차려, **좀**. ……한테도 **잘**릴 뻔해 놓고, 잘났어, 정말.” ― The best I could make out. Bold parts mean they have nonstandard, but common pronunciations of [쫌] and [짤].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expected context: A lady nags at me. (She's concerned.)

> 정신 좀 차려. 좀.

- Snap out of it. Please.

> ㅇㅇㅇ한테도 잘릴 뻔해 놓고.

- You almost got kicked out of ㅇㅇㅇ.

> 잘났어, 정말.

- You're awesome. (sarcastic)
- You're the boss.

Answer (score 1):

1) 정신 좀 차려, 좀. ……한테도 짤릴 뻔해 놓고

@In clip, 좀 sounds like 쫌.

Please, snap out of it. You almost was fired.

2) As far as I know, "resilient" is a positive point.

Here 잘났어, 정말 is "you are something else".